# Trying to use Optimist API help() to print usage()

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I'm new with [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist) and I've done a bit of googling and try outs, but I still can't find an elegant way to add a `--help` option.

I see a [help()](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist#help) option on the documentation. With this I would expect the following to work:

```
var argv = require('optimist')
  .usage('Some usage')
  .alias('l', 'local')
  .describe('l', 'uses local repo')
  .help()
  .argv
```

So on the shell if I typed `./myScript --help` it would show the usage. I know that I can inspect the `argv`for a `-h` or `--help` option and do `console(argv.usage)` to print the usage, but I was trying to use the API instead of hacking it.

Is this a valid question? Thanks for the help.

bitoiu

Comment: what happens when you run ./myScript --help? Do you see the generated usage string? Also consider posting this as an issue on the optimist issues page.

Comment: Hi Noah, I did try that, no generated user string. I did --help, -h, the whole lot. I might as well check the source code. Thanks for the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you want to be able to display a usage, you want to keep a pointer to the object that is returned from the require(). This is because the object returned from the .argv is just a plain object, so there is no way to access the help() or showHelp() functions. Below is a contrived example that I think will point you in the right direction for what you're trying to do.

```
var optimist = require('optimist')
    .usage('$0: This is an example on how to use optimist')
    .describe('h', 'Display the usage')
    .describe('l', 'uses local repo')
    .alias('h', 'help')
    .alias('l', 'local');

var argv = optimist.argv;

if (argv.help) {
    optimist.showHelp();
    process.exit(0);
}

if (argv.local) {
    // Do stuff based on local repo
    console.info('Got the -l/--local flag!');
}
```

Then when you run the code, and pass in either -h or --help, you would get the following output:

```
node ./ex-optimist.js: This is an example on how to use optimist

Options:
  -h, --help   Display the usage
  -l, --local  uses local repo
```

Also note that using the .help function will return the usage as a string, and trying to use .argv after it will make your argv variable 'undefined'.